# Is mining still profitable at this point?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware

Given that Elon Musk is partnering with Ethereum founder Vitalik Buterin to mine Bitcoin sustainably, it surely is still profitable, right?

Answer (score 1):

If mining wasn't profitable, some people would stop mining. The remaining miners would find that mining becomes profitable. It is a self-regulating system.

What it means to mine bitcoin sustainably is probably controversial.